# Azure File Upload from Local Machine

Tags: azure, blob, fileshare

Looking for step by step guide on how to automate upload of .CSV files from my local machine to Azure BLOB/FileShare.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried downloading Storage Explorer. But I don't see options to automate uploading files from particular folder/directory. If you can point me where i can configure in Storage Explorer would be helpful

Comment: Use Azure CLI (az storage blob..) to script things out. Plenty of documentation online.

Comment: Or use AzCopy utility. You can write a batch file and then schedule it using Windows Scheduler.